# User have mails in send box but doesnt really send to internal and external emails

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

I have an old server with Exchange 2007, where one user sends emails and seems to be send, there is no response from mail servers, and the message shows in send folder, in every device he have. But in fact some emails are not being received, for both internal and external emails.

I am still digging in exchange logs but till now, no success.

If you need more info fell free to ask.

Comment: did you check connection from user user end? That mean via outlook?

Comment: he is able to send emails, but some times receivers dont receive his messages, and this user uses Mail App of Macos and IOS, but I dont think that could be the issue

Comment: You need to use Message Tracking to see whether the message was actually sent or not. The item being in Sent Items doesn't really prove anything. If the message doesn't appear in Message Tracking on the server then the email wasn't sent correctly.

Comment: Yes I totally forgot that part, seems like some emails are reaching this email server and other not. I have the confirmation that 90% of the time he sends from his laptop and all emails that didnt reach the server was send by his laptop from different networks.

Comment: Seems like there was a problem with his email client in this case MailApp 12.4. He was able to receive and send only reading confirmations. when he tried to send emails manually, there was no entries at email server. I have used Get-MessageTrackingLog cmd at exchange consule. I will try to upgrade that MailApp first (that email has more then 70GB ...) and if no success, I will remove and re add that account. There is a build in tool to troobleshout email servers connections, but MailApp says that its working fine, but doenst give me any connection verbose log like it does for SMTP servers.